# Getting duplicate ackMessage on ActiveMQ when using Mule Flows for connection

Tags: jms, mule, activemq-classic

When using mule flows as listed below, we are getting duplicate ackMessages on activeMQ. That is, the count of acknowledge messages is double the dispatch Messages.

```
<flow name="dequeueFlow" initialState="stopped">
    <jms:inbound-endpoint queue="my.mq.queueName"
        connector-ref="MyDequeueJmsConnector">
        <jms:transaction action="ALWAYS_BEGIN"/>
    </jms:inbound-endpoint>  
    <processor ref="MyRequestProcessor" />
</flow>

<jms:activemq-connector name="MyDequeueJmsConnector"
                        specification="1.1"
                        connectionFactory-ref="AmqConnectionFactory"
                        disableTemporaryReplyToDestinations="true"
                        persistentDelivery="true"
                        cacheJmsSessions="false"  
                        numberOfConsumers="10"
                        acknowledgementMode="AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE"
                        maxRedelivery="1">
</jms:activemq-connector>
```

In JmsConnector, the acknowledgementMode is set: acknowledgementMode="AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE".

Instead of flows, if we are using default JMS connections, not seeing the issue. Any pointers on how this can be avoided?

Software Versions:

```
Mule Enterprise 3.4.1
ActiveMQ 5.9.0
```

Comment: Are you using the mencioned flow as private flow? If so, please supply the flow that reference it (to give us more detail). Otherwise, the flow should start with an inbound endpoint and not an outbound one.

Comment: Please add more info. Like the configuration of the JmsConnector and possibly entires from the log. It's impossible to guess what may be wrong in your configuration when you don't publish it.

Comment: Thanks @Nuno and Petter. My mistake in the question - the duplicate acknowledgement is with the dequeue flow with inbound-endpoint. I have also added the Jms Connector info. Unfortunately I don't have the logs.